# Why isn't ElGamal a symmetric-key scheme?

Tags: encryption, key-generation, public-key

I was asked about this question by a friend.
He considers that Alice and Bob share a secret key `s=g^(xy)`.
So why isn't it considered a symmentric-key scheme?
According to Wikipedia:

> Symmetric-key algorithms[1] are algorithms for cryptography that use the same cryptographic keys for both encryption of plaintext and decryption of ciphertext. The keys may be identical or there may be a simple transformation to go between the two keys.

I observe that the shared `s` is quite easy to compute by Alice and Bob.

I know there's misunderstanding, but I can't convince myself now.

Comment: Going from `g^(xy)` to m is only _part_ of ElGamal. ​ ​

Comment: Yes, but they do share the same `g^(xy)` at some point of encryption and decryption, right? I know the shared material doesn't make ElGamal symmentric, but why?

Comment: Yes. ​ The shared material isn't ElGamal's decryption key. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`g^x` is the public key of Alice and `x` her private key, while `g^y` is the public key of Bob and `y` his private key.

`s=g^(xy)` is the shared secret between Alice and bob, that can only be computed by them.

Thus, ElGamal is an asymmetric algorithm computing a shared secret that can be used as a symmetric key.

Comment: simple and great answer, congrats.